# mongodb - how to write conditionals within an aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am very new to Mongo, and have a question pertaining to aggregate queries with conditional calculations:

I have a reviews collection, and each document contains a sentiment score. I want to:

1) Group reviews by item

2) Get average sentiment score for each item across all reviews for that item, and sort by this

3) Get total # of reviews for each item group

4) Get total # of positive sentiment reviews for each item (e.g., # reviews with sentiment score > 75)

5) Get total # of negative sentiment reviews for each item (e.g., # reviews with sentiment score < 75)

So far, I have the below query which covers 1-3, but not sure how to get 4/5 in here as well:

```
db.reviews.aggregate( 
    {"$group" : 
        {_id: "$item", 
        sentiment: {$avg : "$sentimentScore"}, 
        count: {$sum: 1 } 
        } 
    }, 
    {"$sort": { sentiment: -1 } } 
)
```

Comment: you need to provide sample documents

Comment: Hi Januka, the only important fields of the documents are the ones shown in the code - "sentimentScore" which is a # between 0 and 100, and "item" which is the name of the item. All I want to do is to add to the code I have such that I have 2 new fields are returned to me for each group of item, one being # of items in that group with sentimentScore < 75 and one for > 75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to have separate `count` field for `sentiment` with negative and positive value with given threshold i.e. `positive - >75` and `negative - <75`, i.e.  total # of positive sentiment and  total # of negative sentiment along with total sentiments.

```
db.sentiments.aggregate([
    {"$group" : 
        {_id: "$item", 
        sentiment: {$avg : "$sentiment_score"}, 
        postiive_sentiments: {$sum: { $cond: { if: { $gt: [ "$sentiment_score", 75 ] }, then: 1, else: 0 } }},
        negative_sentiments: {$sum: { $cond: { if: { $lt: [ "$sentiment_score", 75 ] }, then: 1, else: 0 } }},
        count: {$sum: 1 } 
        } 
    },
     {"$sort": { sentiment: -1 } } 
])
```

Sample data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5991329ea37dbc24842a68be"), "item" : "test1", "sentiment_score" : 50 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132a2a37dbc24842a68bf"), "item" : "test1", "sentiment_score" : 40 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132a4a37dbc24842a68c0"), "item" : "test1", "sentiment_score" : 80 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132aba37dbc24842a68c1"), "item" : "test2", "sentiment_score" : 80 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132ada37dbc24842a68c2"), "item" : "test2", "sentiment_score" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132b0a37dbc24842a68c3"), "item" : "test2", "sentiment_score" : 38 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132b6a37dbc24842a68c4"), "item" : "test3", "sentiment_score" : 78 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132b9a37dbc24842a68c5"), "item" : "test3", "sentiment_score" : 88 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132bba37dbc24842a68c6"), "item" : "test3", "sentiment_score" : 58 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132c4a37dbc24842a68c7"), "item" : "test3", "sentiment_score" : 98 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132cba37dbc24842a68c8"), "item" : "test4", "sentiment_score" : 65 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132d2a37dbc24842a68c9"), "item" : "test4", "sentiment_score" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599132d6a37dbc24842a68ca"), "item" : "test4", "sentiment_score" : 10 }
```

//Result:

```
{ "_id" : "test3", "sentiment" : 80.5, "negative_sentiments" : 3, "positive_sentiments" : 1, "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "test1", "sentiment" : 56.666666666666664, "negative_sentiments" : 1, "positive_sentiments" : 2, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "test2", "sentiment" : 49.333333333333336, "negative_sentiments" : 1, "positive_sentiments" : 2, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "test4", "sentiment" : 35, "negative_sentiments" : 0, "positive_sentiments" : 3, "count" : 3 }
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked great.